# Laravel 5.7 Passing a value to a route in a controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

My controller posts a form to create a new page.  After posting the form I need to redirect the user to the new page that will have the contents for that page that were entered in the previous form.  If I simply do return `view('mynewpageview', compact('mycontent'));` where my mycontent is the object used to execute the `$mycontent->save();` command, I carry the risk for someone refreshing the url thus posting the same content twice by creating a new page.

Instead I would like to redirect the user to the actual page url.

My route is
`Route::get('/newpage/{id}', 'PageController@pagebyid');` and if I use `return redirect()->route('/newpage/$pageid');` where `$pageid = $mycontent->id;` I get Route not defined error.

What would be the solution either to stop someone from resubmitting the content or a correct syntax for passing the parameter?

Comment: You try to use `return redirect()->route('/newpage/' . $pageid);`?You are putting the variable itself on the string not his value.

Comment: I did.  And it still shows the same error even though the path is modified accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer that works for me is -

1. Give your route a name in the routes file
2. Then pass the parameters with an array as shown below in the controller.

return redirect()->route('newpageid', ['id' => $pageid]);

Answer (score -1):

With basic (unnamed) routes, the correct syntax was `return redirect('/newpage/'.$pageid);`

You have already found out you can alternatively use [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes).

Last but not least, thanks for having considered the "double submit" issue! You have actually implemented the [PRG pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) :)